# How to delete duplicates within the list of rules with certain accuracy?

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

hello!

I know that all my questions are about the same list of rules, but I'm still trying to understand the Wolfram Language logic... So, given the list of rules:

```
intermediateResult1 = {Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 
   336.4317195415496826172`4.526896935319825, 
  Subscript[Abx, 4, 5] -> 358.7006528377532958984`4.554732167095748, 
  Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 378.44673919677734375`4.578004767586344, 
  Subscript[Abx, 6, 5] -> 395.4161212444305419922`4.597054371666505, 
  Subscript[Aby, 1, 5] -> 36.781777392763615353`3.5656327116671127, 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 5] -> 33.1913761270843679085`3.521025258796362, 
  Subscript[Aby, 3, 5] -> 32.4560489654541015625`3.5112956499036425, 
  Subscript[Aby, 4, 5] -> 33.5718250274658203125`3.5259749509535157, 
  Subscript[Aby, 5, 5] -> 35.5354518890380859375`3.5506618425494563, 
  Subscript[Aby, 6, 5] -> 37.34320068359375`3.57221153856355, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 1] -> 329.5073566436767578125`4.517865115179159, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 2] -> 327.6947731971740722656`4.51546951434628, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 3] -> 323.5337643623352050781`4.50991961085035, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 4] -> 317.9532122611999511719`4.502363216991488, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 6] -> 306.2719948891899548471`4.486107287302384, 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 1] -> -45.9602017402648925781`3.662381926336777, 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 2] -> -34.1088933944702148438`3.532867629683822, 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 3] -> -12.6594895720481872559`3.1024161953723484, 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 4] -> 11.9279458522796630859`3.076565658940116, 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 6] -> 44.6705413808922457974`3.650021215899404, 
  Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 336.4315013885498046875`4.5268966537094135, 
  Subscript[Abx, 4, 5] -> 358.7000494003295898437`4.5547314364872, 
  Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 378.44620513916015625`4.578004154716907, 
  Subscript[Abx, 6, 5] -> 395.41620635986328125`4.597054465150702, 
  Subscript[Abz, 1, 5] -> 1.2710712253319798037`2.1041698872195984, 
  Subscript[Abz, 2, 5] -> -8.1248037660552654415`2.909812880500324, 
  Subscript[Abz, 3, 5] -> -2.6828441619873046875`2.428595446598665, 
  Subscript[Abz, 4, 5] -> 7.2073822021484375`2.8577775529853255, 
  Subscript[Abz, 5, 5] -> 11.15843963623046875`3.0476034683691697, 
  Subscript[Abz, 6, 5] -> -1.21844482421875`2.085805867472421, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 1] -> 329.45794677734375`4.51779998752455, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 2] -> 327.68582916259765625`4.51545766063914, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 3] -> 323.5235595703125`4.509905912265384, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 4] -> 317.94913482666015625`4.502357647559863, 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 6] -> 306.2722103486594278365`4.4861075928243626, 
  Subscript[Abz, 2, 1] -> -7.56097412109375`2.87857775160733, 
  Subscript[Abz, 2, 2] -> -8.53708648681640625`2.9313096811589183, 
  Subscript[Abz, 2, 3] -> -10.927783966064453125`3.0385321007524007, 
  Subscript[Abz, 2, 4] -> -11.77996063232421875`3.071143839076471, 
  Subscript[Abz, 2, 6] -> 2.9972137859149370342`2.4767177215014726}
```

. As you can see, in the list there are some rules, that almost duplicate each other, for example `Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 336.43171954154968261724.526896935319825` and `Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 336.43150138854980468754.5268966537094135`. We've got the difference between them of some value (and in the "program" that I have to create there will always be such a difference). My goal is to delete duplicates with given precision. I realized that with the following code: `DeleteDuplicates[SetPrecision[intermediateResult1, 4]]` and it works, but the function "SetPrecision" works with all the digits of the number as I understand, but I just need the function working with after point digits. For example, if the values of the rules will be about 10,000 (`intermediateResult1 = {Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 12336.431719` and the others will be of the same order) that way won't be useful... I know that there is a function SetAccuracy, but the code `DeleteDuplicates[SetAccuracy[intermediateResult1, 4]]` doesn't get the result as I need. Can you please explain me how to do it? Also I can imagine that there are fundamentally different ways to implement this (delete duplicates even if the values of the rules are different with certain accuracy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
intermediateResult2 = DeleteDuplicates[intermediateResult1,
   2*Abs[(Values[#1] - Values[#2])/((Values[#1] + Values[#2]))] < 
     10^-4 &];

Length /@ {intermediateResult1, intermediateResult2}

(* {40, 32} *)
```